# Number REGEXP with PHP

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I try to accept file names from 01.jpg to 12.jpg with this regexp :

```
preg_match('/^([0-1][0-2]\.jpe?g)$/i', $_FILES['Filedata']['name'])
```

01.jpg, 10.jpg, 11.jpg, 12.jpg are OK

but not 02.jpg to 09.jpg !!!

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 '/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.jpe?g$/i'
```

Comment: I did : preg_match('/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.jpe?g$/i', $_FILES['Filedata']['name'])

Comment: The one I posted just above works like a charm ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])\.jpe?g$
```

`0[1-9]` takes care of `01`, `02` and so on till `09`

`1[012]` which is same as `1[0-2]` takes care of `10`, `11` and `12`

Note the use of `()` carefully. Since `|` has the least precedence in regex operators:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]\.jpe?g)$
```

(from the other upvoted answer) is incorrect as it is treated as:

```
^(0[1-9]
```

OR

```
1[0-2]\.jpe?g)$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/N7ekgP3XrH)

Comment: This will aceppt 01,1-9,10-12 but not 02 - 09.

Comment: Read the first line of the question. His current solution works exactly like yours.

Comment: But OP wants to match 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12. Not just a few of them

Comment: Misunderstood the question :D